# Xilinx: Common synthesis Warnings

Tags: verilog, fpga

```
module InstructionRegister(ir_in,ir_out,ir_r_enable,ir_w_enable,clock);
    input clock;
    input [7:0] ir_in;
    output reg [7:0] ir_out;
    input ir_w_enable;
    input ir_r_enable;
    reg [7:0] insreg;
    initial
    begin
        ir_out=8'b0;
    end
    always @(posedge clock)
        begin
            if(ir_w_enable)
                insreg <= ir_in;
            else if(ir_r_enable)
                ir_out <= insreg;
        end
endmodule
```

---

Warning:Due to constant pushing, FF/Latch  is unconnected in block (for all 8 bits)

---

Now, I searched for the warning and the most common explanation was value of register is not changing but here the value depends on the input which may vary...so why this warning?

Comment: which version are you using? ISE or Vivado?

Comment: Are trying to synthesize only this module? The warning might be in the context of use in a parent model.

Comment: @Greg No, I am synthesizing my top module in which these warnings are displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your module defintely is not the cause of this warning. It's one (or more) of the signals that go to this module from the module that instantiates it.

"Constant pushing" means that the `ir_in` bus is connected to is a constant value, so the register always store the same value, hence the synthesizer optimizes the module throwing away the register.

This is something that usually happens when a module is being tested and, for commodity reasons, you connect inputs to a constant value.